# Timing of values in Combine Framework's `append` operator?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204685-append) on the Combine Framework's `append` operator says:

> This operator produces no elements until this publisher finishes. It then produces this publisher’s elements, followed by the given publisher’s elements.

So I would expect the first publisher's elements to be produced all at once, with no regard for the timing by which they are actually published by the first publisher. But that is not the case.

For example:

```
    [1,2,3,4].publisher.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) {
        Just($0).delay(for: 1, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    }.append( Just(100) )
```

As you can see, the first publisher produces `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` at one-second intervals. According to the documentation, `append` should *wait* until all four values have been produced — that is, for four seconds — and then republish those values at all once. But that isn't what happens. What I see is just what the first publisher itself produces, namely, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` at one-second intervals. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the documentation is wrong.

Another way to see this is to start with a first publisher that *never* finishes:

```
    Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        .append(Just(Date()))
```

If the documentation were right, that would never produce any values at all, because the first publisher never finishes. But instead it produces the first publisher's values every second.

The actual strategy used by `append` (Publishers.Concatenate) seems to be this:

- It subscribes to the first publisher and republishes its values as they arrive.
- If and when it receives a finished completion from the first publisher, it subscribes to the second publisher and republishes its values as they arrive.

The header gets this wrong too:

> This operator produces no elements until this publisher finishes.

My guess is that in the early stages of development Apple probably did implement `.append` (Concatenate) as described in the docs, but then they realized this was just wrong and changed it without changing the documentation to match.